# Enable bluetooth on lenovo ideapad y480

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, lenovo, ideapad

I've search every crevice of the internet and can still not find how to enable bluetooh on my Lenovo ideapad Y480,

rfkill list returns 'no' on all

lsusb suggests a bluetooh adapter is not found:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2f1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have no keypress to enable bluetooth. Couldn't find anything on bios to enable bluetooth. Installed bluetooth manager, bluetooth support, and who knows what else.

Any suggestions? I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 but had the same problem in 14.04.

Comment: Did you use usb bluetooth or built-in bluetooth?

Comment: This is a built in bluetooth adapter.

Comment: I think it will be not recognized by using lsub. It can be turned on via bluetooth indicator (right top panel), you should have it, it should be there by default. If you don't have, try to turn on via setting (just type 'bluetooth' in the dash). Another way is by re/start it via command line: sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start

Comment: The bluetooth cannot be enabled for some reason

Comment: So i do have wireless key (fn+F5) but this key is mapped to turn on/off wifi but in the windows version a pop up would appear allowing turn on/off bluetooth and/or wifi. So I believe the problem is I need to switch bluetooth on without using the shortcut key but a replacement for that. please help its been bugging me for months

Comment: This problem solved itself with the recent updates  I think. Bluetooth icon appears and pairs correctly now. I have turned off the laptop accidentally with battery removal and crashed it. Not sure if that had an effect so I credit the updates.