# To enable Bluetooth adapter in Lenovo G50-30 in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo

I know this thread [Enable bluetooth on lenovo ideapad y480](https://askubuntu.com/q/648907/25388).
I recall having problems with the Wifi connection with this laptop, similar thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551522/netis-wf2120-wifi-adapter-drops-signal-within-seconds). 
Now, I noticed that I get the error *no bluetooth adapters* found when trying to connect to the laptop my bluetooth devices. 
This laptop has bluetooth adapter so the thing is in software.

`lsusb` does not give the following but not bluetooth adapter

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 062: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Bus 001 Device 064: ID 046e:52cf Behavior Tech. Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07e6 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My kernel is the newest Linux 3.16.7-ctk11.

### Outputs from Jyjyc's commands which I had to run now in Debian 8.1, since I do not have the latest Ubuntu anymore on this disk.

The command `uname -r` gives *3.16.0-4-amd64*. 
The `lsusb` gives still the same as above.
The command `lspci` gives

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 0f23 (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f48 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4c (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4e (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 0f12 (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

The command `lsmod | egrep -i 'blue|bt|rfcomm'` gives

```
btusb                  29721  0 
bluetooth             374429  2 ath3k,btusb
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 18867  4 cfg80211,bluetooth
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
usbcore               195340  7 ath3k,btusb,uvcvideo,rtsx_usb,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci
```

---

How can you force enable bluetooth in 14.04?

Comment: What is your kernel version? `uname -r`?

Comment: And please give output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: Please provide output for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Masi Why do you provide information other than you are asked to provide?

Comment: I provided information what was asked but he removed his answer. I provided thr info in debian because I have it now only with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do and install Bluetooth control manager *blueman*

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Problem not in drivers but in controlling bluetooth.